# How to connect to MariaDB on AWS from C# over SSH

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, ssh, mariadb

I am trying to connect to a MariaDB instance on AWS using C# over an SSH connection. I am able to get connected using MySQL workbench with the following configuration;

MySQL Workbench Configuration:
[image: MySQL Workbench Configuration]

But the code I build in C# cannot create the SSH connection. Here's the code (just test code, so not pretty!)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Renci.SshNet;
using MySqlConnector;

using System.IO;

namespace MariaDB_1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var sshServer = "aa.bb.cc.dd";
            var sshUserName = "ubuntu";
            var sshPassword = "";
            var databaseServer = "test-api.xyz.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com";
            var databaseUserName = "test_user";
            var databasePassword = "***************";
            var keyfile = "C:\\Users\\test\\Documents\\test.pem";

            var (sshClient, localPort) = ConnectSsh(sshServer, sshUserName, sshPassword, keyfile, databaseServer: databaseServer);
            using (sshClient)
            {
                MySqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
                {
                    Server = "127.0.0.1",
                    Port = localPort,
                    UserID = databaseUserName,
                    Password = databasePassword,
                };

                using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                };
            }
        }

        public static (SshClient SshClient, uint Port) ConnectSsh(string sshHostName, string sshUserName, string sshPassword = null,
                       string sshKeyFile = null, string sshPassPhrase = null, int sshPort = 22, string databaseServer = "localhost", int databasePort = 3306)
        {
            // check arguments
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sshHostName))
                throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(sshHostName)} must be specified.", nameof(sshHostName));
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sshHostName))
                throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(sshUserName)} must be specified.", nameof(sshUserName));
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sshPassword) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sshKeyFile))
                throw new ArgumentException($"One of {nameof(sshPassword)} and {nameof(sshKeyFile)} must be specified.");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(databaseServer))
                throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(databaseServer)} must be specified.", nameof(databaseServer));

            // define the authentication methods to use (in order)
            var authenticationMethods = new List<AuthenticationMethod>();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sshKeyFile))
            {
                authenticationMethods.Add(new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(sshUserName,
                    new PrivateKeyFile(sshKeyFile, string.IsNullOrEmpty(sshPassPhrase) ? null : sshPassPhrase)));
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sshPassword))
            {
                authenticationMethods.Add(new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(sshUserName, sshPassword));
            }

            // connect to the SSH server
            var sshClient = new SshClient(new ConnectionInfo(sshHostName, sshPort, sshUserName, authenticationMethods.ToArray()));

            // *** This next line is where I get the error: Permission denied (publickey) ***
            sshClient.Connect();

            // forward a local port to the database server and port, using the SSH server
            var forwardedPort = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", databaseServer, (uint)databasePort);
            sshClient.AddForwardedPort(forwardedPort);
            forwardedPort.Start();

            return (sshClient, forwardedPort.BoundPort);
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get when I try to execute the `sshClient.Connect()` is `Permission denied (publickey)`. Any help would be appreciated! Again, the MySQL Workbench can access the database just fine, so there's something wrong in my code, just not sure what!